# How to send data from a controller function a view in Laravel 4 to change the page layout

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-4

I have a controller function that redirects a user based on an $id that is checked.  What I would like to do, is on the page the user is redirected to, access the value of $id so that I can display a modal or not.  So something like this:

```
public function action_session($provider, $id = null) {

if(!is_null($id)) {

            return Redirect::to('/fans/'.Auth::user()->url_tag);
        }

}
```

I would like to send the $id variable to the `'/fans/'.Auth::user()->url_tag` view, so that I a modal either pops up or not.  How would I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have to redirect with $id:

```
return Redirect::to('/fans/'.Auth::user()->url_tag)->with('redirected_id', $id);
```

Then, in the new request, you can get it with:

```
$id = Session::get('redirected_id');
```

As [Jason Lewis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280329/jason-lewis) said in the comments, it's related to flash data: http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data. Basically, when you redirect your current request to a route/url, sending some data to it, Laravel flashes that information in the Session, so you can grab it in the next request.

Comment: About to post an identical answer. OP, this is referred to as [flash data](http://laravel.com/docs/session#flash-data).